# Creating react-router Routes in a function

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router

Is it possible to create the `<Route>` elements through a function? I would like to display different routes/pages and the application is not aware how many they are. The pages are in the state stored in an array of page objects. Each page object have an id, title, path and body elements (so far). I think that my Router should look like this:

```js
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="page1" component={CommonPage}/>
      <Route path="page2" component={CommonPage} />
      <Route path="page3" component={CommonPage} />
      <Route path="page4" component={CommonPage}/>
      <Route path="page5" component={CommonPage} />
      <Route path="page6" component={CommonPage} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

And I would like to define it with a function like:

```js
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      {
        mapPagesToRoutes(pages) 
       }
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)

mapPagesToRoutes(pages)  {
  return pages.map( page => () {
    if(page.type === 'CommonPage' {
       return <Route path={page.path}  component={CommonPage}
    }
  }
}
```

Q1: How is this done?
Q2: How do I identify each with something other than the path. Can I use some sort of key=page.id in `<Route>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass properties to your child route components, you can do something like this:

```
        <Route path={page.path} component={() => <CommonPage someProp={page.someProp}/>}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically create React Routes then you can use a route with a parameter, like so. Here's your Router:

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="/page:pageNumber" pages={this.state.pages} component={CommonPage} />
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

Then in your CommonPage component have something like this:

```
render() {
    return(<div>This is {this.props.params.pageNumber}</div>);
}
```

That should give you the ability to navigate to any /pageX route. Then in CommonPage component you can compare the pageNumber parameter and the pages property (available via `this.props.route.pages`) to see if the current page number is valid

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Jayce444